# Session variable stored in asp.net core 2.0 is giving null for the first time and is working fine when refreshed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

**Here is my c# brief code.**

```
public JsonResult GetValuesForReports(bool IsNew)
        {
            string ZoneDetailsForSession = GetZoneDetails();
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("ZoneDetails", ZoneDetailsForSession);

            //Some code here
            return Json(ListReportValues);
        }
```

**Here is my Javascript Code**

```
var ZoneDetailsVB = '@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("ZoneDetails")';
console.log(ZoneDetailsVB);
```

The problem is the Session variable stored is giving me Null for the first time, but when i refresh the page and run, the function hit is giving me proper results.
Please tell me the cause and suggest me a solution.

Comment: When are you calling `GetValuesForReports` method from your code??

Comment: You probably set the session variable after retrieving in the first time.

Comment: Making an ajax call and trying to access the session value in the success callback of the same ajax. @IpsitGaur

Comment: Change `@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("ZoneDetails")` to call a method that checks whether the value is `null` (and if it is `null` it calls `HttpContext.Session.SetString("ZoneDetails", ZoneDetailsForSession)`).

Comment: May be its happening the way u said @MarkusDresch But how do I do this, I mean any changes so that it wold work?

Answer (score 1):

Sessions have a server-side and client-side component. That client-side component is the session cookie, which is set by the server returning the response with a `Set-Cookie` header. This prompts the client to set the cookie locally. On the next request and all subsequent requests, then, the client will pass this cookie back in the `Cookie` header of the request. Until this happens, the session is not initialized. That's why it works on subsequent requests, but not the first. You need a new request to be able to get at the session data.